# I need help to build ionic with iOS i have this problem :

Tags: ionic-framework, build

ionic cordova build ios

> ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=ios
> Error: Unknown argument: platform
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

```
    ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=ios exited with exit code 1.
    
    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
    information.
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` and your `angular.json` files.

Comment: i have un error after do this command : npm i -g native-run

npm WARN config global --global, --local are deprecated. Use --location=global instead.
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/native-run/bin/native-run
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/native-run
npm ERR! errno -13  (I don't know how I can share package json and angular json

Comment: please check my answer hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running into permission issues. If you are installing `npm-packages` then it might possible that you are getting an EACCES error when trying to install a package globally. This means you do not have permission to write to the directories `npm` uses to store global packages and commands.

Try running commands:

```
sudo chmod u+x -R 775 ~/.npm
sudo chown $USER -R ~/.npm
```

or you can just run any npm command with sudo, that should get resolve your issue.

```
sudo ionic cordova build ios
```

I'd recommend you to take a look at https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: after do this command sudo ionic Cordova build ios I have this error : Error: Could not find the '@ionic/cordova-builders:cordova-build' builder's node package.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
        
        ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=ios exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

Comment: `sudo npm install @ionic/cordova-builders` use this command and try again

Comment: now I have this :[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

Comment: can you write this command and copy the log:

`sudo ionic cordova build ios --verbose`